# how to delete all edges with specific weight in igraph python?

Tags: python, igraph

I am new to Python so sorry if this is so simple,I am trying to delete all `edges` which its `weight` is `zero`but with this code I was just able to delete one edge at a time, How to make it in away that it will delete all the edges ?

```
 ig.summary(graph_like)
IGRAPH D-W- 5390 40276 -- 
graph_like.delete_edges("weight"==0);
ig.summary(graph_like)
IGRAPH D-W- 5390 40275 --
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`graph_like.delete_edges("weight"==0)` does not work because it evaluates as follows:

1. Python evaluates `"weight" == 0`, which is a comparison of the string `"weight"` with the number zero. The result of this comparison is `False`, a value of type `bool`.
2. The result of the above expression is then fed into `graph_like.delete_edges()`, which expects a list of edge IDs as its first argument. Since edge IDs are integers, it will cast `False` into an integer, making it equal to zero, then igraph deletes the edge with ID zero.

Instead of that, you need to select all the edges with zero weight:

```
graph_like.es.select(weight=0)
```

where `graph_like.es` represents the edge sequence of the graph (i.e. all the edges in order), and its `select()` method restricts the edge sequence based on certain criteria. Here, `weight=0` is a keyword argument of `select()` (note that there is only a single equals sign between `weight` and `0` and `weight` is not a string here). The result of the above expression is the sequence of all the edges that have zero weight. Then you can simply invoke the `delete()` method of this edge sequence:

```
graph_like.es.select(weight=0).delete()
```