# igraph - shortest path from edges with defined weights

Tags: python, graph-theory, igraph, shortest-path, weighted-graph

I am currently trying to compute shortest paths between ***every pair of connected nodes*** in a very large weighted graph (160K nodes, 15 million edges).

I would like to find the number of edges in the shortest path between every two nodes, when all edges with a weight >= the weight of the edge between the two nodes are deleted.  If a path cannot be found, I will take the shortest path as 1 (i.e. the deleted edge connecting the nodes).

Is it possible to use `igraph` v0.9.11 to do this (essentially [GraphBase.shortest_paths()](https://igraph.org/python/doc/api/igraph._igraph.GraphBase.html#shortest_paths), with the option to ignore edges with a weight above a given threshold)?  I would rather not hand code a solution given the size of the graph (I'm guessing the igraph implementation would be better and hopefully written in a faster non-python language).  Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
g = ig.Graph.TupleList(data_all.itertuples(index=False), 
                           directed=False,
                           edge_attrs = ['percent', 'length_difference'] 
                           )
for edge in g.es:
    threshold_weight = edge.attributes()['length_difference']
    shortest = g.my_pretend_shortest_paths(source = edge.source, target = edge.target, weights = 'length_difference', mode = 'all', ignore_weights_over = threshold_weight) #should not alter original graph obj
    if shortest = []:
        shortest_paths += [(edge.source, edge.target, threshold_weight, 1)] 
    else:
        shortest_paths += [(edge.source, edge.target, threshold_weight, len(shortest))]
```

My current solution is below, but I'm hoping there's a better way than copying a big graph and doing costly graph operations outside of `shortest_paths`, 15 million times.  This takes 6-700 seconds to analyse 500 edges within a test graph with only ~250K edges (giving a predicted runtime of ~230 days for 15 million edges):

```
g = ig.Graph.TupleList(df.itertuples(index=False), 
                       directed=False,
                       edge_attrs = ['percent', 'length_difference'] 
                       )
shortest_paths = []
for edge in g.es:
    temp_g = copy.deepcopy(g)
    threshold_weight = edge.attributes()['length_difference']
   
    #delete edges in the graph copy with a length_difference edge attribute >= current edge's.  
    #https://stackoverflow.com/a/28951383/11357695  
    temp_g.es.select(length_difference_ge = threshold_weight).delete()
    
    shortest = temp_g.shortest_paths(source = edge.source, target = edge.target, weights = 'length_difference', mode = 'all')
    if shortest = []:
        shortest_paths += [(edge.source, edge.target, threshold_weight, 1)] #will plot these downstream
    else:
        shortest_paths += [(edge.source, edge.target, threshold_weight, len(shortest))] #will plot these downstream
```

Ideally, this will complete within about 12 hours max - I can leave it overnight but beyond that it gets a bit awkward.

Thanks,
Tim

***EDIT***

I have optimised it further to remove the copying of the large graph and removing redundant processing, but it still takes about a minute to process 1-2000 nodes (i.e. ~1 week for 15 million nodes assuming everything scales linearly).  Any better solutions would be appreciated!

```
def ec_list_to_g(es):
    edges_formatted = []
    for e in es:
        att = e.attributes()
        edges_formatted += [(e.source, e.target, att['percent'], att['length_difference'])]
    return ig.Graph.TupleList(edges_formatted, 
                directed=False,
                edge_attrs = ['percent', 'length_difference'] 
                )


g = ig.Graph.TupleList(df.itertuples(index=False), 
                       directed=False,
                       edge_attrs = ['percent', 'length_difference'] 
                       )
shortest_paths = []
for edge in g.es:
    threshold_weight = edge.attributes()['length_difference']
    if threshold_weight <= 1:
        continue
    target_es = g.es.select(length_difference_lt = threshold_weight)
    sub_g  = ec_list_to_g(target_es)
    shortest = sub_g.shortest_paths(source = edge.source, target = 
                edge.target, weights = 'length_difference', mode = 'all')#follow on as before
```

Comment: With 160,000 vertices you need a matrix of 25 billion elements to store the result. That requires 200 GB of contiguous memory _just for the result_, not to mention intermediate steps. Even forgetting about how long the computation would take, you should probably have a computer without about a terabyte of memory.

Comment: Thats interesting, do you mean it will need a terabyte just to make the graph datastructure itself?  I've had issues with other libraries and softwares but igraph seems to make a graph fine on my laptop (which is fairly bog standard).

Comment: No, not the graph, but the result matrix for all pairs between 160,000 vertices. But maybe you didn't mean _all_ pairs, just connected pairs? You say all pairs, but the question reads like connected pairs only.

Comment: Ah no, thanks for the spot - only connected pairs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of igraph 0.10 (and all earlier versions), graph modifications such as deleting edges is expensive. It causes the graph to be re-built from scratch, thus it takes time proportional to the graph size, even if you remove only a single edge.

When you perform weighted shortest path calculations, an efficient way to *effectively* disable an edge without actually removing it is to set its weight to infinity (`float('inf')`). Using this technique is likely to significantly improve performance.